# Condicion en dentro de un ciclo for

Tags: javascript, html

me surge una duda con respecto a las condiciones dentro de un querySelector, lo que trato de hacer es mostrar o no un botón que genero a partir de un ciclo for como se muestra a continuacion:

```
function LlenarTabla(){
document.querySelector('#tabla_docente tbody').innerHTML = '<tr> </tr>';
for (let i = 0; i < contratos.length; i++) 
document.querySelector('#tabla_docente tbody').innerHTML += `
<tr>
    <td style='visibility:collapse; display:none;'> ${contratos[i].id_cont} </td>
    <td>${i+1} </td>
    <td> ${contratos[i].nombre} </td>
    <td> ${contratos[i].nombre_tipo}</td>
    <td> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <form action='./reportes/reporte_${contratos[i].c_tipo}a.php' method='POST' target='_blank'>
                <input type='hidden' name='docente_ciclo' value='${contratos[i].c_ciclo}'>
                <input type='hidden' name='docente_dep' value='${contratos[i].c_depe}'>
                <input type='hidden' name='docente_id' value='${contratos[i].c_doc}'>
                <input type='hidden' name='tipo' value='${contratos[i].c_tipo}'>
                <input type='submit' name='' value='generar' class='btn btn-primary'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="desc_asig(${contratos[i].id_cont})" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
            Titular
        </button>
    </td>
</td>
</tr>
`;
}
```

Pretendía colocar una condición en medio de querySelector,

```
if(contratos[i].c_tipo==2){
`<td>
    <button> </button>
 </td>`
}
```

pero esto no me lo permite (o no he decifrado como), les agradecería mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con algo así:

```js
contratos = [{
  'nombre': 'Paco1',
  'nombre_tipo': 'TipoNombre1',
  'c_ciclo': 'CCiclo1',
  'c_depe': 'CDepe',
  'c_doc': 'CDoc',
  'c_tipo': '2',
}, {
  'nombre': 'Paco2',
  'nombre_tipo': 'TipoNombre2',
  'c_ciclo': 'CCiclo2',
  'c_depe': 'CDepe',
  'c_doc': 'CDoc',
  'c_tipo': '1',
} ]

function LlenarTabla() {
  document.querySelector('#tabla_docente tbody').innerHTML = '<tr> </tr>';
  for (let i = 0; i < contratos.length; i++) {
    let boton = ''
    if (contratos[i].c_tipo == 2) {
      boton = `<td>
    <button>Botón</button>
 </td>`
    }

    document.querySelector('#tabla_docente tbody').innerHTML += `
<tr>
    <td style='visibility:collapse; display:none;'> ${contratos[i].id_cont} </td>
    <td>${i+1} </td>
    <td> ${contratos[i].nombre} </td>
    <td> ${contratos[i].nombre_tipo}</td>
    ` + boton + `
    <td> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <form action='./reportes/reporte_${contratos[i].c_tipo}a.php' method='POST' target='_blank'>
                <input type='hidden' name='docente_ciclo' value='${contratos[i].c_ciclo}'>
                <input type='hidden' name='docente_dep' value='${contratos[i].c_depe}'>
                <input type='hidden' name='docente_id' value='${contratos[i].c_doc}'>
                <input type='hidden' name='tipo' value='${contratos[i].c_tipo}'>
                <input type='submit' name='' value='generar' class='btn btn-primary'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="desc_asig(${contratos[i].id_cont})" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
            Titular
        </button>
    </td>
</td>
</tr>
`
  }
}
LlenarTabla()
```

```html
<table id="tabla_docente">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

donde lo que hacemos para insertar el código que necesitas es simplemente cerrar el string actual con el acento invertido (grave), luego el símbolo de suma **+** y la variable que contiene el resultado del **if** que necesitas hacer, para terminar con otro símbolo de suma **+** y después abrimos de nuevo la cadena de texto con el acento invertido:

```
` + boton + `
```

Usando esta sintaxis lo podrias hacer de muchas otras formas, aunque yo lo que he hecho es crear la variable **boton** para dejarlo más limpio y así no poner el condicional entre los simbolos de suma.